# WPF Combobox with view source and dropdown source

Tags: wpf, filter, combobox, dropdown

I am sure others have done this but I can't find any examples or I just don't know how to word it.

WPF Combobox with EmployeeID as valueMember and EmployeeName as DisplayMember.  EmployeeID is saved to the table as ApprovedByID.

Let's say I have a WPF Combobox for a field that holds the employee id of somebody who approved a purchase.   I don't want the list filtered for displaying the name, but when it comes to changing the employee, I want to filter the items in the dropdown to only be current employees.

The goal, on old records, shows who approved it.  On new records or when editing an old record, I only want current employees selected.  I've done this before in Winforms but that was long ago and I forgot :(

Can this be done with a WPF Combobox or do I need to create a control with a TextBlock for display and a Listbox as the dropdown?

```
<ComboBox   Grid.Row ="5" Grid.Column="1"   Margin="10, 2"
                    Attached:ComboBoxAttached.AllowNull="True"
                    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Edit}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="FullName" 
                    SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding 
                    Current.APPROVED_BY_ID}" />
```

Comment: Please post your code... it will help. This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If I just filter out the list bound to ItemsSource on the dropdownOpen event, then the current value is blanked out regardless if an item is selected in the dropdown.  I need something with separate lists....one for the display and one for the dropdown.